# Traverse Neo4J nodes ordered by relation property in Java

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

Is it possible to traverse nodes ordered by a property given by relations in the Java API?

```
Source node *--- 4 ---> * Node 1
            |
            +--- 3 ---> * Node 2
            |
            +--- 2 ---> * Node 3
            |
            '--- 1 ---> * Node 4
```

Where *'s are nodes and the numbers between -'s are relation properties. 
Such that the above would give the nodes 4, 3, 2 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to get all those relationships and sort them first then. If you're using that in a traversal then such a behaviour can be encoded in a RelationshipExpander.

Comment: Could you please link to some documentation or examples using the RelationshipExpander. I can't seem to find any good?!

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples that you can work from at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_relationshipexpander . Does that help? You can go to the GIThub source and work your way from there?